# Replacing strings within strings based on my array - getting object error

Tags: arrays, vba, runtime-error

```
Sub clean()

Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CleanAry
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'copy Column B to C
'Range("B1:B1048576").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("C1:C1048576")

'array for clean up

CleanAry = Array("..", "__")

lastrow = ws.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cel In Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
    For i = LBound(CleanAry) To UBound(CleanAry)
            cel = cel.Replace(What:=CleanAry(i), _
                            Replacement:=".", _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
    Next i
Next cel
End Sub
```

I am trying to create an array of string combinations that will parse through a particular column and remove those string combinations from the existing strings in the cells.

However, my code only seems to work when I have one string in my array, and not when I add additional strings. I get the error :

> "object required" for the "cel=..." section.

Haven't really coded in VBA consistently. Do help me figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you are facing, but `Range.Replace` method returns a boolean. Don't use your target cell to catch it since you need the value in target cell.

Comment: Another approach is `cel.Value = Replace(cel.Value, CleanAry(i), ".")`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add some checks if you expect there could ever be errors in the range being cleaned.  The whole process would be much faster using an array.

```
Sub clean()

    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CleanAry, v, arr, r As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'copy Column B to C
    'Range("B1:B1048576").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("C1:C1048576")

    CleanAry = Array("..", "__")   'array for clean up

    lastrow = ws.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Value
    For r = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(r, 1)
        For i = LBound(CleanAry) To UBound(CleanAry)
                v = Replace(v, CleanAry(i), ".")
        Next i
        arr(r, 1) = v
    Next r
    Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Value = arr
End Sub
```